# Sending and storing the sensor data on cloud

Tags: database, cloud, mqtt

I have interfaced a microcontroller to a sensor. Now I want to update this sensor data to the cloud continuously, so I can access this data anytime. First I used MQTT protocol to connect microcontroller to the server and send the sensor data continuously to the server. But this data is not stored on the server. So now I need to save this server data to database so I can access it anytime.
My questions are: Is this the correct way for sending the data on the cloud? Is there any other way for updating the sensor data on the cloud? And what are the ways to save the server data to database? Are there any private servers available which can store tha data in database automatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All the data use any protocol to send on the cloud. You can use mqtt/https etc whichever you want. You need to store on the cloud and fetch it from there when needed. YOu can use some free services which provide the storage and sending/retrieving the data.